# Problems to connect to NXT brick

Tags: python, nxt-python

I'm using `nxt-python 1.2.0`, `PyBluez 0.22`, `PyUsb 1.0.0` with Python 2.7 and `LibUSB-Win32 1.2.6.0` on `Windows 10`. I tried to connect to my NXT brick with bluetooth and with usb but I could not get it to connect either way.

With bluetooth, I get the following error:

> IOError: a connection attempt failed because the brick didn't reply fast enough

When I execute one of the example programs.

However, python still manages to give the bluetooth adress of the brick (or something else I dont know) using 'host' even if it's not turned on ! `nxt.locator.find_one_brick()` gives `nxt.bluesock.BlueSock object at 0x04481630`

When I try to use usb, I get:

> USBError: [Errno None] libusb0-dll:err [control_msg] sending control message failed, win error: The specific file cant be found.
>
> nxt.locator.find_one_brick() gives nxt.usbsock.USBSock object at 0x0750ADF0

Can you please help me to connect to the brick with at least one of the both methods. Thanks